# Why is this way to solve the differential equation wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking at the following problem:

> [image]

There is a solution and I understand it but I tried to answer it by writing:

$$y'=\frac{(y+1)^2}{y}=y+\frac{1}{y}+2$$

Integrating it to obtain:

$$y=y^2+\log(y)+2y+c$$

And solving for $c$ in $y(2)=0$. The trouble is that it seems this is not a solution to the differential equation in the problem but I can't figure out why. I' ve tried to use Mathematica to check for equality but it failed.

Comment: On the right side, the integration happens w.r.t. $y$, and on the left side, w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Looks like you flipped your $y'$ to $ \frac{dx}{dy}$ ... you can't do that! The answer in the text book is correct.

Comment: So, in my case, am I switching the _order of respect?_ 

$\tiny \text{(Okay, that is a terrible and nonsensical expression but it sounded so awesome that I couldn't avoid using it!)}$

Comment: Which book is it ?

Comment: @LostInSpace [Tenenbaum/Pollard](https://www.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486649407).

Comment: Thank you Billy +1 for your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y'=\frac{(y+1)^2}{y}=y+\frac{1}{y}+2$$
Note that: $$y'=\frac {dy}{dx} \ne \frac {dx}{dy}$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{(y+1)^2}{y}$$
You interverted the $dy$ and the $dx$  then integrate ? The answer won't be correct. Maybe Leibniz notation is better $ ( \frac {dy}{dx})$, you avoid this kind of mistakes.
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{(y+1)^2}{y}$$
$$ \int \frac {ydy}{(y+1)^2}= \int dx $$
Substitute $u=y+1$:
$$ \int \frac {(u-1)du}{u^2}= \int dx $$
$$ \int \frac {du}{u}- \int \frac {du}{u^2}= \int dx $$
That's easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\int \frac{dy}{dx} \ne y$$ the correct rule is $$\int \frac{dy}{dx} dx=\int dy=y$$

Comment: Wait, why $\int \frac{dy}{dx} \ne y$?

Comment: @Billy Rubina because in the integration we don't say $\int f(x)$ but we always say $\int f(x) dx.$